# How do I install Roundcube?

Tags: php

Does anybody know how to install [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) on ubuntu Precise.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with following their wiki?

- Install [the requirements](http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Howto_Requirements)...

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ^lamp-server postfix
  ```

  This is just PHP and MySQL. The requirements specify various "at least" figures for various PHP configuration items. I've no idea how far they differ from Ubuntu standards, but it's all there.
- Follow the wiki's instructions: http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Howto_Install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Universe repository (see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) enabled and you can install it via apt (or whatever frontend you like).